# Tool to draw software architecture

Tags: drawing, presentation

Does someone know if there exist some free software that will allow me to easily draw software architecture?

I DON'T mean UML, workflow, diagram, or other technical stuff BUT "presentation-oriented" drawing, like [this](http://www.d-simlab.com/images/dsimfed.jpg).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope [this](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en) helps, I found that one, while looking for free alternatives to MS Visio.

Here the [source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-free-open-source-alternative-to-microsoft-visio/) (which also comes among the first results in a google search for free alternative to Visio)